# Flask : understanding POST method to transmit data

Tags: python, http, post, flask

my question is quite hard to describe, so I will focus on explaining the situation. So let's say I have 2 different entities, which may run on different machines. Let's call the first one *Manager* and the second one *Generator*. The manager is the only one which can be called via the user.

The manager has a method called `getVM(scenario_Id)`, which takes the ID of a scenario as a parameter, and retrieve a BLOB from the database corresponding to the ID given as a parameter. This BLOB is actually a XML structure that I need to send to the Generator. Both have a Flask running.

On another machine, I have my generator with a `generateVM()` method, which will create a VM according to the XML structure it recieves. We will not talk about how the VM is created from the XML.

Currently I made this :

**Manager**

```
# This method will be called by the user
@app.route("/getVM/<int:scId>", methods=['GET']) 
def getVM(scId):
    xmlContent = db.getXML(scId)  # So here is what I want to send
    generatorAddr = sgAdd + "/generateVM"   # sgAdd is declared in the Initialize() [IP of the Generator]

    # Here how should I put my data ? 
    # How can I transmit xmlContent ? 

    testReturn = urlopen(generatorAddr).read()
    return json.dumps(testReturn)
```

**Generator**

```
# This method will be called by the user
@app.route("/generateVM", methods=['POST']) 
def generateVM():
    # Retrieve the XML content...
    return "Whatever"
```

So as you can see, I am stuck on how to transmit the data itself (the XML structure), and then how to treat it... So if you have any strategy, hint, tip, clue on how I should proceed, please feel free to answer. Maybe there are some things I do not really understand about Flask, so feel free to correct everything wrong I said.

Best regards and thank you

PS : Lines with routes are commented because they mess up the syntax coloration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless i'm missing something couldn't you just transmit it in the body of a post request? Isn't that how your `generateVM` method is setup?

```
@app.route("/getVM/<int:scId>", methods=['GET']) 
def getVM(scId):
    xmlContent = db.getXML(scId)  
    generatorAddr = sgAdd + "/generateVM"   

xml_str = some_method_to_generate_xml()
data_str = urllib.urlencode({'xml': xml_str})
urllib.urlopen(generatorAddr, data=data_str).read()
return json.dumps(testReturn)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen

Comment: Well the problem is that I did not know the syntax of the post body, and I did not find any example using it. So I follow you on the theory here, however I got a TypeError exception raised (must be string or buffer, not dict), so I think it's moaning about the body you inserted

Comment: @NNzz yes sorry it was supposed to be a `The data argument must be in standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format; see the urlencode() function below.` not a dict.  Updated

Comment: Just checked it before you give this answer. Thank you anyway, I accepted your answer ;)